# Python: Reformat CSV file

Tags: python, csv, format, reformat

I have a CSV file like this:

```
Additional,0        
No     1284         
Yes      44 
Total count,1286
gender,0        
Female    918           
Male      904           
Total count,1822
```

Whenever there's a 0 in column 2 (like the 0 after gender and Additional),I'd like to start reformating it to something like this:

```
Additional,1286     
No,1284         
Yes,44 
gender,1822     
Female,918          
Male,904
```

How do I do that? I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: This isn't even a valid csv as far a column count is concerned. "No", "Yes", "Female" and "Male" are not even properly comma separated. Where are these new values coming from?

Comment: Femal 918 is in the same cell. It is from a different script and I get only the CSV file and not the script that generates it. The total count is the count of unique values calculated from another set of CSV files. @CodyBouche

Comment: *"How do I do that?"* A good starting point is to write some code,  ask a question in SO and show us what you have tried so far if you are stuck at some problems/errors you are getting...

Answer (score 1):

file.csv

```
Additional,0        
No,1284         
Yes,44 
Total count,1286
gender,0        
Female,918           
Male,904           
Total count,1822
```

code

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as csvread:
    reader = csv.reader(csvread)
    with open('out.csv', 'wb') as csvwrite:
        writer = csv.writer(csvwrite)
        for row in reader:
            frow = []
            for i, val in enumerate(row):
                val = val.strip()
                if val.isdigit():
                    val = int(val)
                if i == 1 and val == 0:
                    if frow[0] == 'Additional':
                         val = 'something'
                    elif frow[0] == 'gender':
                         val = 'something else'
                frow.append(val)
            writer.writerow(frow)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I cannot hardcode the values. There are tons of them.

Comment: Ok well you never specified an external file to map from so there is no possible way for me to know how to map...

Comment: I don't have an external file either. All I have is this poorly formatted file.

Comment: Ok so if you want these "0" values dynamically replaced then you can either hard code the logic or there must be another file you are getting the data from...